# using groff inside of a flatpak container

Tags: gedit, flatpak, groff

I am trying to call the program `groff` from inside a gedit flatpak (external tools plugin).
The flatpak can access the groff binary, but `groff` looks for files at `/usr/share/groff`, while in flatpak, this path is mapped to `/var/run/host/usr/share/groff`.
What is the proper way of accessing a binary like this? Or rather the datadir of a binary like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to set environment variables

```
export GROFF_TMAC_PATH=/var/run/host/usr/share/groff/site.tmac
export GROFF_FONT_PATH=/var/run/host/usr/share/groff/site-font
```

Comment: wow, I have been using groff for over a year and did not know these env variables existed, thanks!